# Avoid firestore notification to be received by the sender as well

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

1. Sender sends the data to firestore
2. firestore stores the data
3. firestore broadcasts the data to all the connected clients (including sender)

Is their any way where the sender does not receive the notification?
OR
If the sender receives the notification, is there any way to discard the received data?

Comment: Do you mean avoiding to send the PUSH notification to the data sender, or are you talking about a listener update?

Comment: @FrizzTheSnail avoiding sending the push notification to the data sender solves my problem or if the sender receives the same, i need some kind of data in the notification from which i should be able to discard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid sending PUSH notification to the sender himself, you need to track the sender ID inside the sent data.

To set the sender ID into the data automatically in the cloud function you can take it from the context:

```
exports.myDataUpdate = (data, context) => {

  var dataToWrite = data;
  dataToWrite['senderId'] = context.auth.uid;

  // Store dataToWrite to firestore....
};
```

Then in the corresponding cloud trigger ( onUpdate/onCreate ), you should find the sender ID you set when you prompted the update.

When sending the notification, send it only to the 'other' concerning users, excluding the sender.

This implies you are managing the notification tokens yourself and you have a cloud firestore structure where you mantain the users' notification tokens.

When receiving a listener update, you just compare the sender ID with the current user ID and drop the update if you want that.

Comment: solution seems to be acceptable, but i wanted something from the firestore end as i did not want to add the senderId from my end

Comment: If you are performing the update in a cloud function, you have the caller's userID in the context received as the second parameter in the function call (context.auth.uid).
You can add the userID to the received data, then in the database trigger use the sender ID as described above.